# How to conceal an affiliate link on a button

Tags: javascript, php

How would I conceal the real link below to the button "SHOW ME HOW" and put in a false link, so that anyone who scraped the page using View Source/HTTrack and copied the page on their site would still have my affiliate link in, eg:

```
<a href="false link in here that would not matter if it is changed">
<span class="tve_btn_txt" id="btcnlkk2">SHOW ME HOW!</span>
</a>
```

and the Javascript associated is:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $("#btcnlkk2").click(function() {
        $(window).attr('location','http://www.TRUEREFERRERLINK.com')
    });
    $("#btcnlkk2").mouseover(function() {
        $('#btcnlkk2').css('cursor','pointer');
    });    
});
```

The  solution above does not work for me - I just gave it as an example.

Thanks.

Comment: Even if the JS you tried worked... Why wouldn't someone be able to edit the JS?

Comment: Use an url shortener.

Answer (score 0):

Link to a redirect method on your own site.

mysite.com/redirect.php?value=123

and then on the redirect php page you can associate 123 with the true url. A database containing the value for each id would be a good idea.